# Enable Update button only when password is shown strong

Tags: password, profiles

Would like to find out here if there is any way I can disable the "Update" button under "Account Management" and enable it until a Strong password is detected as shown in the screenshot?

[image]

Currently, the "Update" button is enabled automatically when a "medium" strength password is being identified.

Thanks in advance!
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using jquery for this,
please put this code inside the function.php of your theme.

```
add_action('admin_head','custom_handler_for_pass_js'); 
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_handler_for_pass_js' ) ) {
function custom_handler_for_pass_js()
{
   ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.wp-generate-pw').click(function(){
            jQuery("#pass1").keyup(function(){
                if(jQuery( "#pass1" ).hasClass( "strong" )){
                    jQuery('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }else{
                    jQuery('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

  }}
```

This code is working, if it's not working in your WP please check for a class name and make sure they are matching.
In case of any issue let me know.

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, thanks for the code snippets. It works!

Comment: Glad to hear that.